# Admin rights with smart install maker

Tags: permissions, windows-xp, installation

I purchased Smart Install Maker. Everything seems to be working fine, except the admin rights.

Even when I uncheck the field "require Administrator rights" my final install package can't be installed by a normal user who hasn't got admin rights.
The installation will start, but during the copying process it prompts "unable to copy file xyz.dll". This message appears for every file in the package.
I guess that the install program is unable to copy the files due to restricted rights. On an admin account, it worked fine.

We tested on Win XP.

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: it turned out, that a normal xp user (non-admin) has no writing rights for the folder C:\Programm Files\. When changing the install path to another dir during the installation, everything goes fine. #Weird #Windows